# Unable to reduce Docker max disk image size on Windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10

I'm trying to reduce the maximum Disk image Size in the settings,
All though I can move and save the minimum size, it doesn't get saved.
[image]

When the docker restart to save the changes, it automatically changes back to 59.6GB

[image]

How can i fix the size to 16GB?

Answer (score 1):

It's actually an issue with Docker for Windows: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4725

You can update the disk size manually from an admin powershell:

```
Resize-VHD -Path 'C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\vm-data\DockerDesktop.vhdx' -SizeBytes 16gb
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I upgraded to version 2.2.0.5 of the Docker Desktop Community and it worked.

Windows 10 Pro
Version 10.0.17763